# touchesEnded sent to removed SKNode

Tags: sprite-kit, uitouch

In my scene there are SKNodes(and subtypes) being added and removed. Now there is a problem when a node is removed on which a touch event started but not ended. In my case I tap on an SKSpriteNode, then the sprite is removed from the scene. When I now raise my finger (or mouse button in the simulator) the app is crashing.
How would I remove an SKNode with all current UITouches on it?

**edit:**

This is the crash I get when the touch ends on a removed node:
[image]

**edit2:**

This is the code which is called when the touch has ended:

```
-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    for(UITouch *touch in touches){
        if(touch!=activeTouch){continue;}   // track only one UITouch
        CGPoint tPos = [touch locationInNode:self.parent];
        currentlyPressed=NO;
        bool touchIsInFrame=CGRectContainsPoint(accumulatedFrame, tPos);
        if(clickOnlyValidInsideFrame==NO || touchIsInFrame==YES){
            if(block!=nil){
                block();
            }
            if(clickEndedSel!=nil && selectorObj!=nil){
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Warc-performSelector-leaks"
                [selectorObj performSelector:clickEndedSel];
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**edit3:**

I don't have a solution but a workaround. The removal of the node has to be scheduled for the update method called by SpriteKit. Also the issue seems to be related the constellation were the SpriteKit scene is added as an overlay to a SceneKit view.

Comment: It sounds like you are removing on the touchBegin. Why do you care about the click end? It would helpful if you better described what your expected behavior is. For example, if you take a button. You'll notice it doesn't respond until a touch inside. This is just an example and you may not want that behavior.

Comment: The removal is done in the function which called by the selector. I've stripped down the problem and found out that this problem occurs when the button is removed outside of the update method.

Comment: What class does `touchesEnded` belong to? And what is `selectorObj` set to? You should show the code to `clickEndedSel`

Answer (score 1):

I think to best way to solve this would be to centralize UITouch handling. The scene could be the one to handle UITouches. This way you'd avoid nodes from having touchesEnded called when they're already deallocated. You can test the node at the location of the touch and call removeFromParent on it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this might be a valuable hint to solve the problem, an answer really needs to demonstrate the solution.  Please [edit] to provide example code to show what you mean. Alternatively, consider writing this as a comment instead.

Comment: I had this concept in a previous project and it became a mess. Sure, it is totally fine on a smaller scale.

Comment: Your approach could still be done by hiding the node that you want to remove, then, on touchesEnded you simply test whether your node is hidden or not and remove it

Comment: @KugelnMMXVI, while you may have had a negative experience when you centralized touch logic, it is the better approach. I've worked on really large projects and input code is always centralized.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a touch event that is holding onto a node, you really should be using a strong reference to preserve the node until the event is finished.

If you could provide code, I could give you a better answer, but for now it is as simple as:

```
//instance variable
var nodeIsTouched : SKNode?


//inside touch code
...
nodeIsTouched = touchedNode
```

Then on your touches ended event, you check if the node is on the scene  (unless you have another way to determint it was killed).

```
if node.scene != nil
{
  //do touch code
}
else
{
   //maybe do some other code
}
nodeIsTouched = nil
```

Comment: This would be much easier if I could just call [self retain] in touchesBegan and [self release] at the end of touchesEnded.

Comment: no you do not want to do that, that means you could forget to release.  Wait, your touch code is INSIDE the node you are touching?  Then you have some other problem going on

Comment: Where else would the touch code be? This is a button implementation which calls blocks or selectors after touch events. But it doesn't matter what it is doing at those events because touchesEnded is still called when the node is released.

Comment: it shouldn't be,  let me try and write an example to verify the behavior

Comment: Maybe the problem is that my button itself calls a function which removes the button.

Comment: couldn't tell you  After I make my test we can work from there

Comment: Ok, I got a workaround. Instead of just calling removeFromParent I queried the removal until the next call of the update method.

Comment: So I  finished my test,  it does not crash.  Instead of a work around, we should find your problem

Comment: please post your touchesEnded code, something in there crashed

Comment: In fact, it does not even fire touchesEnded,  so you are somehow retaining it and keeping it to the scene.... which means you are removing it in the didBeginContact I bet

Comment: I've posted the code of touchesEnded but I think the problem is somewhere else. When I am retaining the button there is no crash. I've spend more than 5 hours on this issue and now I am rather happy with my workaround. Maybe it is a bug of SceneKit? Note that the crash occurs in 'SCNSpriteKitEventHandler' which is a SceneKit class.

Comment: I appreciate your efforts. We did not find the root of the problem but you somehow lead me to a workaround. My code is working now and I can continue. Thank you.

Comment: looks like [selectorObj performSelector:clickEndedSel]; could be the problem,  clickEndedSel may not exist in selectorObj

Comment: If that was a problem it would crash at this point. I've already double checked this line because I am not happy with those #pragma lines. 'selectorObj' and 'clickEndedSel' are parameters which are passed during the initialization of the button.

Comment: well you never told us what line it is crashing on,  your stack trace says you are inside your touch event

Comment: The stacktrace says that it crashes inside 'SCNSpriteKitEventHandler' which is part of SceneKit were I can't see the source code. But from using breakpoints I know that SCNSpriteKitEventHandler would call touchesEnded/touchesBegan of my class.

Comment: I have no idea how your classes are laid out, I can only go by what I am seeing